# How to assign the selected data to a specific graph. ( VBA script )

Tags: vba

Am trying to auto select the source data for a chart using vba script. The script is designed to include the newly added column as a source data to the graph. But there are multiple graphs in the same sheet that has to be updated,

Comment: hi, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question to better reflect these guidelines

Comment: Pls read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Before posting a query

Comment: Have you considered converting your source data to an Excel table which extends automatically as you add new data to it.  You could then reference `=[Table1[ColumnNames]]` in your chart data source.  In any case, if you want a VBA solution, you will have to add code showing what you have tried and where it is broken.  SO isn't a code writing service - you will have to pay for one of them though.